# .swf converted to .mp4 color not correct in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, flash, mp4

I have a .swf file that I converted to .mp4 file to be used with HTML 5 video.  The file displays correctly in VLC but the colors are wrong in Windows Media Player.  I converted the .mp4 to .ogv and .webm for all browser compatibility as well.  When viewed in browsers it displays correctly in all browsers except IE, where it has the same wrong colors as media player.  Is there something I can do so colors display correctly in all browsers?

Comment: What software did you use for transcoding swf to mp4? it seems either your original swf has frame coloration issues or the transcoding process did make them appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar color problem with a Flash-to-MP4 movie in IE, although at the time I didn't view the file in Windows Media Player, so not 100% sure it's the same issue.
But the answer could be this:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12785/why-is-mp4-black-background-gray-in-internet-explorer-11